# Spring + Eureka Connection refused to registered service

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, netflix-eureka, connection-refused

- I have a setup structured of Spring Boot & Eureka running on Docker.
- I have two Spring Boot applications: `discussion-service` and a `cairo-service`.
- `cairo-service` needs to make a call to `discussion-service`.

  - Request made using Eureka via `@LoadBalanced RestTemplate` bean
- RestTemplate attempts to reach connection to `discussion-service` is attempted:

  - Prepared URL: `http://discussion-service/discussion/c3f3e424-bc67-4984-b808-e14ddf493766`

The issue is that a ConnectException is thrown. Shelling into the Cairo container, pinging Discussion container is successful, endpoints are responding as expected via cURL. The URL fed into curl was `http://discussion/discussion/c3f3e424-bc67-4984-b808-e14ddf493766` as that's the name of the service generated by Docker Compose. Externally, *no port is 80 or 8080* - each port is some iteration greater than 8080.

I have hope my Spring implementation is perfectly functional. For some reason when I run the three Spring Boot apps (`discussion-service` (port 8080), `cairo-service` (port 8081), and `nile-service` (port 8761) - local eureka server) it works work excellently.

Lastly, it's worth noting I've only just begun learning this setup for a few days now.

```
2020-04-14 19:38:47.850 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Accept=[application/json, application/*+json]
2020-04-14 19:38:48.088  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty  : Flipping property: discussion-service.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.ac
tiveConnectionsLimit = 2147483647                                                                                                                                                                                                        2020-04-14 19:38:48.142  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.n.u.concurrent.ShutdownEnabledTimer    : Shutdown hook installed for: NFLoadBalancer-PingTimer-discussion-service
2020-04-14 19:38:48.143  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.netflix.loadbalancer.BaseLoadBalancer  : Client: discussion-service instantiated a LoadBalancer: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=discussion-service,current li
st of Servers=[],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {},Server stats: []}ServerList:null
2020-04-14 19:38:48.154  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer      : Using serverListUpdater PollingServerListUpdater                                                                                        2020-04-14 19:38:48.195  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty  : Flipping property: discussion-service.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.ac
tiveConnectionsLimit = 2147483647
2020-04-14 19:38:48.198  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer      : DynamicServerListLoadBalancer for client discussion-service initialized: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=discussion-s
ervice,current list of Servers=[nile:8080],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {defaultzone=[Zone:defaultzone;      Instance count:1;       Active connections count: 0;    Circuit breaker tripped count: 0;       Active connections per se
rver: 0.0;]
},Server stats: [[Server:nile:8080;     Zone:defaultZone;       Total Requests:0;       Successive connection failure:0;        Total blackout seconds:0;       Last connection made:Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 1970;      First connection
made: Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 1970;     Active Connections:0;   total failure count in last (1000) msecs:0;     average resp time:0.0;  90 percentile resp time:0.0;    95 percentile resp time:0.0;    min resp time:0.0;      max resp
time:0.0;       stddev resp time:0.0]
]}ServerList:org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.eureka.DomainExtractingServerList@283933a4
2020-04-14 19:38:48.234 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Failed to complete request: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://discussion-serv
ice/discussion/c3f3e424-bc67-4984-b808-e14ddf493766": Connection refused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2020-04-14 19:38:48.242 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception i
s org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://discussion-service/discussion/c3f3e424-bc67-4984-b808-e14ddf493766": Connection refused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Co
nnection refused] with root cause

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:503) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:492) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:648) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:597) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:182) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:341) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:362) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1256) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1194) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1082) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1016) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerRequestFactory.lambda$createRequest$0(LoadBalancerRequestFactory.java:61) ~[spring-cloud-commons-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:144) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:125) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:99) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerInterceptor.intercept(LoadBalancerInterceptor.java:58) ~[spring-cloud-commons-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:77) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:739) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:674) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:315) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at com.supaham.learn.controller.QuestionController.discussion(QuestionController.kt:53) ~[classes!/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:109) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]

2020-04-14 19:38:48.249 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2020-04-14 19:38:48.254 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletRespons
e)
2020-04-14 19:38:48.276 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
2020-04-14 19:38:48.282 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 500
2020-04-14 19:38:49.158  INFO 1 --- [erListUpdater-0] c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty  : Flipping property: discussion-service.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.ac
tiveConnectionsLimit = 2147483647
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some faffing around and a lot of water it turned out to be the server *implicitly* being registered on port `8080` of the container.

I  was baffled by what could be causing this issue considering that the containers are able to communicate via cURL. I `@Autowired EurekaDiscoveryClient` and began digging through its properties, specifically searching for anything regarding services.

1. `client.services`: returns `[cairo-service, discussion-service]`. Great!
2. first instance of `discussion-service` has an id of `fc8feb8bb803:discussion-service`, exactly like the Eureka UI says!
3. Check out the `metadata` from that same instance: returns a map of `{management.port=8080}`. Mmm that sounds relevant.

Somewhere in the middle of all this, my mind registered the slightest possibility that maybe the aforementioned "id" should be representing its port too, similar to. Lo and behold, ports are involved somehow.

On my local development machine, Eureka UI states `discussion-service` is registered to `MY-PC:discussion-service`. One important point to make here is that `cairo-service` is registered to `MY-PC:cairo-service:8081`, using an explicitly defined port of 8081. Note that I am not currently using docker for development, instead I just run services as needed (on peaceful ports), hence why `MY-PC` is being used as opposed to a docker container hostname. The system is functional as mentioned earlier, `cairo-service` can reach `discussion-service`. Why? Well, it turns out that Eureka works a lot better at reaching the right address and port when on its own network (or host?).

The moment the services became isolated, Eureka couldn't represent the right connection to `discussion-service` because it fails to include the default implied port of 8080 as part of the URL, causing the consumers to reference the URL using the default HTTP port 80, e.g. `http://discussion-service:80/discussion/c3f3e424-bc67-4984-b808-e14ddf493766`.

How do we solve this problem?

Turns out explicitly setting the server port causes Eureka to pick it up as part of the service id. The problem can be resolved in various ways, however my preference is the least constraining. I use the `server.port` property in the `application.properties` file. In my case I'm using `application.yml`

```yaml
server:
  port: 8080
```

And just like that, an entire day's worth of headache resolved in few characters.

I want to thank the Spring team for making this tool so easy to use. However, it is also the culprit in that there are so many tools being used within the framework, but also my environment, that makes it hard to understand which point is failing exactly